# in asp mvc, can I dynamically generate javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On my aspx view, I would like to generate javascript where some parts are generated:

before generation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var A = 'an id';
    var B = "http://www.yahoo.com" + <%= Model.pathname %>;
</script>
```

After generation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var A = 'an id';
    var B = "http://www.yahoo.com/videos/index.htm" ;
</script>
```

is this possible? what options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var A = 'an id';
    var B = "http://www.yahoo.com<%= Model.pathname %>";
</script>
```

Maybe the IntelliSense is not completely right in Visual Studio, but it will work.

Comment: Why the shock MedicineMan?  This seems similar to what one could do in classic ASP in some ways.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's entirely possible, javascript is not executed untill way after all of this stuff is rendered, you have pretty much whatever options you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should work fine, just surround the directive with single quotes for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var A = 'an id';
    var B = "http://www.yahoo.com" + '<%= Model.pathname %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible.

If the JavaScript code is in your view, then simply doing the: `<%= Model.pathname %>` would work.